# How To Get Elegy RH8 GTA V

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

how do I get the Elegy in GTA V story mode? And if so, can I get it without making a Rockstar social club account thingo?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can only get the Elegy RH8 if you are part of the *Rockstar Social Club.* It is on the *Legendary Motorsports* website for free (if you have a *Rockstar Social Club* account of course). 
**BUT,** if you are playing on a PC, you can buy it for $95,000 **WITHOUT** a *Social Club* account

Comment: Is Rockstar Social Club worth it?

Comment: Yes, it is very worth it. It is also free! With Rockstar Social Club, you can also join crews.

Comment: Sorry to drag on, but is that how you change your crew colour? And can crew colour be changed in story mode as well? What else does the Rockstar Social Club allow/offer?

Comment: I think you need to go on the Social Club website, log in to your account, and manage crew. Other things that Social Club offers are special events and offers. Social Club also can be linked with another Rockstar game, Max Payne 3.

Comment: So say I don't have PSN (on PS4 at the moment) and I'm just playing story mode, will I need to get PSN to use Rockstar Social Club? Or will I be able to link it some other way?

Comment: You don't need PSN to make a Social Club account, but you do need one to play GTA Online. Social Club is not required to play GTA Online, although it's recommended.

Comment: So if I make a Social Club account, I can get the Elegy in story mode? Even if I don't have PSN?

Comment: You need to link your Social Club account to your PSN account in order to get the Elegy Online or in Story Mode. My point is, you need PSN as well to get the Elegy.

Answer (score 0):

In story mode you can go to the one garage for each account and walk to the exit and press right on the d-pad when your by the door and a list of cars will pop up.  And one of the words in the list will say elegy select that and u will leave that garage and spawn out side of it with the elegy.